# How to find its owner DataGrid and DataGridRow from DataGridCell in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, relationship

In an event handler for a Command for a DataGrid, I get DataGridCell in ExecutedRoutedEventArgs. However, I couldn't figure out how to get its associated DataGrid and DataGridRow. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

You probably *want* to set some sort of `RelativeSource` binding that can get you the "parent grid/row" via a `{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}`, but your question got me thinking...

You could:

Use Reflection:

```
var gridCell = ....;
var parentRow = gridCell
         .GetType()
         .GetProperty("RowOwner", 
               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
         .GetValue(null) as DataGridRow;
```

Use the `VisualTreeHelper`:

```
var gridCell = ...;
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(gridCell);
while(parent != null && parent.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow))
{
    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I think is a complete answer...

```
    private void Copy(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = GetParent<DataGrid>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
        DataGridRow row = GetParent<DataGridRow>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
    }

    private T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject d) where T:class
    {
        while (d != null && !(d is T))
        {
            d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);
        }
        return d as T;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do is by passing one or both of the needed elements in as a CommandParameter:

```
<MouseBinding 
    MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" 
    Command="cmd:CustomCommands.Open" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid}}" />
```

If you need both, you could add a multi-value converter that combines them into a `Tuple` (or leave it as an object[])

Then in your code-behind you can access it by using `e.Parameter`